# Creating virtual disk with arbitrary size

Tags: windows, filesystems, fat16

I want to do some "experimentation" to learn about the file systems starting from FAT16.

The idea is to use a C++ program to manipulate a disk at byte level and then see how it is read by Windows.
In short, format the disk to FAT16, create files, create directories, rename files, delete files, delete directories, change properties of files, see what happens if I tamper with sector number of files e.t.c. It wil all use the C++ readfile and writefile functions.

Having a "virtual disk" will make things considerably easier as no hardware will be made corrupt and the disk can be "reset" easily.

Yes, I am an electronic engineer so have to work at low level of hardware.

Comment: Why not just create a RAM disk and use that ?

Comment: What is a ram disk?

Comment: It's just a virtual disk which takes a chunk of RAM and makes it look like a disk drive - most operating systems have this capability as standard - you didn't mention what OS you are working with though...

Comment: I am using Windows 10,

Comment: OK - I've added a Windows tag for you - if you can't find the control panel or whatever for setting up a RAM disk (I know almost nothing about Windows) then you could try asking on [su] (or maybe just Google it ?).

Comment: By the way, since you have mentioned it, what is the usual purpose of ram disks?

Comment: RAM disks are a bit of an anachronism these days, but are still sometimes useful - they basically give you a small fast temporary disk which can be used to speed up certain file-based operations. These days file system caches and other techniques tend to obviate the need for RAM disks.